# MySQL trigger - how to update specific row in another table

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables

```
**Table tb_data**
tb_id
timestamp
pagid
proid
status
(and many more)

**Table tb_units**
pag_id
pag_sn
user
latest_profile
latest_status
latest_feedback
latest_timestamp
```

Whenever a new row is created in tb_data, i would like some values updated in tb_units. In tb_units pag_id is unique and every number only exists once.
How do I trigger this, so the new values in tb_data are updated in tb_units? pagid equals pag_id and the corresponding values proid should update latest_profil, status should update latest_status, timestamp should update latest_timestamp

In the end I would like to end up with the latest pagid input to tb_data to be available in tb_units, since tb_data will contain multiple rows from the same pagid

I hvae tried several different aproaches, and have read a lot of examples, but I just don't get how these triggers work!

Latest example, that doesn't work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_units
AFTER INSERT ON tb_data
BEGIN
UPDATE tb_units 
   SET latest_profile = tb_data.9C, 
       latest_status = tb_data.91 
 WHERE pag_id = tb_data.86;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but something like this should work

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_units
AFTER INSERT ON tb_data
BEGIN
UPDATE tb_units 
   SET latest_profile = new.proid, 
       latest_status = new.status 
 WHERE pag_id = new.pagid;
END
```